# Nodejs How to pass an Object instance over Files?

Tags: node.js

Im trying to pass an object instance to other objects.

**Index.js**

```
const A = require("./A.js");
A.getInstance().init();
```

**A.js**

```
const B = require("./B.js");
class A {
    b;
    instance;
    static getInstance() {
        if (this.instance == undefined)
            this.instance = new A();
        return this.instance;
    }
    init() {
        this.b = new B();
    }
    test() {
        console.log("Hello World!");
    }
}
module.exports = A;
```

**B.js**

```
const A = require("./A.js");
class B {
    constructor() {
        A.getInstance().test();
    }
}
module.exports = B;
```

When I try to run an error pops up saying

> A.getInstance() is not a Function!

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency. Something not supported by node.js nor ES6. Which IMHO is a good design feature as cyclic dependency is a sign that your software is badly designed. Remove the cyclic dependency. Otherwise what you are doing should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a circular dependency. It happens when two modules requires each other. When `A` tries to import `B` at that time module `B` tries to import `A`, But moudule `A` hasn't been resolved yet. That's why this problem happens.

To solve this problem you need to do dependency injection. Let's say `A` is the most important module here. What we can do is import `B` from `A` but add a method in module `B` to pass the dependency from module `A` when it's ready.

##### A.js

```
const B = require("./B");
// Do your work here
const A = { /* Whatever here */ };
// Now pass the dependency to B
B.setA(A);
```

If it still doesn't solve your problem then you really need to think about the design of the project. If the code is highly related then move all the code to the same file.